# How to pass a List<> in REST POST method using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass a List of similar values in the request body of a REST post method using spring mvc. Below is my sample code. Please let me know what is correct way to send the List in requestbody.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userlogin/details", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> insertLoginDetails(
        @RequestParam("username") String userName,
        @RequestBody List<String> listOfID) {
    return eventAnalyzerHelper.insertUserLoginDetails(userName,
            listOfID);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't _send_ anything in a request body, you _receive_ from the request body. What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I usually make a dedicated FooList class that holds a `List<Foo>` field. That way the JSON ends up being something like: `{"foos": [ {"a":1}, {"b":2}, ... ] }`.

Answer (score 6):

This example might help you

Each `text input` has the same name fruits:

```
<form method="post">
  Fruit 1: <input type="text" name="fruits"/><br/>
  Fruit 2: <input type="text" name="fruits"/><br/>
  Fruit 3: <input type="text" name="fruits"/><br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

On your `controller’s handler method`, you can obtain the list of all fruit names by binding it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addFruits(@RequestParam("fruits") List<String> fruits) {
  // ...
}
```

Basically Spring handles on its own, if you have multiple fields with same path/name, it automatically tries to cast it into Array or List.

Comment: Even if ankur-singhal answer is form related, a controller does not care about **how** the request was constructed, and you can still construct it with javascript or any other scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the List in an Object. Its better designed that way. You could make this object generic and reuse it multiple times in other controllers if needed. Just be aware that you have to follow the same structure when constructing the object in the calling system.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addFruits(@RequestBody ListWrapper fruits) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you plz share a example for ListWrapper class to construct the list of fruits?